# What are the solutions for $2 \sin^2 \theta − 1 = 0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find all solutions of the given equation.

I have $\pi/3 +2k\pi$ and $2\pi/3+2k\pi$.

However, the computer program I am using says I am wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The given equation is equivalent to

$$\sin\theta=\pm\frac{\sqrt2}2\iff\left(\theta\equiv\pm\frac\pi4\mod2\pi\right)\lor\left(\theta\equiv\pm\frac{3\pi}4\mod2\pi\right)$$

Comment: Thats what I submitted, but I am being told by the computer that my answer is wrong.

Comment: @Cetshwayo, another way to write this solution is $\theta=\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{k\pi}{2}=\frac{\pi}{4}(1+2k)$ among others. Your software might be expecting another format.

Answer (score 2):

Note that

$$2\sin^2 t -1= 2\sin^2 t-(\sin^2 t+\cos^2 t)$$

$$=\sin^2 t-\cos^2 t$$

$$=-\cos2t$$

so the equation is equivalent to $$ \cos 2t=0$$

This happens exactly when $2t=\pi/2 +\pi k$ for integral $k$. That is,

$$
\boxed{t=\dfrac{\pi}{4}+\dfrac{\pi k}{2}}
$$